# Code doesn't execute when it is supposed to

Tags: c, cs50

The function "check" goes through; however, the if statements are not working even if they are supposed to. The whole point of this code is to find the least number of coins needed for the change (user input). I made `if` statements that should work; however, they don't. I think it might be because I am trying to compare a float and an integer but I am not too sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

float change;
int count;
int check();

int main(void)
{
    printf("Please enter the change in dollars : $");
    change = GetFloat();
    change = change*100;
    printf("¢% f\n", change);
    int check();
    printf("%i \n", count);
}

int check(void)
{
    count = 0;

   if (change > 24)
   {
       change = change - 25;
       count++;
   }
   else if (change > 9)
   {
       change = change - 10;
       count++;
   }
   else if (change > 4)
   {
       change = change - 5;
       count++;
   }
   else if (change > 0)
   {
       change = change - 1;
       count++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to keep calling `check` in a loop until change is 0. And you should be using an `int` to keep track of the `change`.

Comment: How can I use an int for change? The user may want to input a decimal number since this is related to money.

Comment: `float temp = GetFloat(); int change = temp * 100.0 + 0.5;` So you read a float from the user, but convert to an `int` after multiplying by 100.

Comment: `float` to `int` truncates by default. Adding 0.5 forces rounding instead. For example, if you type `3.10`, then `temp * 100.0` will be slightly less than 310, something like `309.99999`. If you truncate to an `int`, then you get 309, but if you round you get 310.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
int check();
```

does not call the function. It is another declaration. Perhaps you meant to use

```
check();
```

**Update**

You need a `while` loop in `check()`.

```
int check(void)
{
   count = 0;
   while ( change > 0 )
   {
      if (change > 24)
      {
         change = change - 25;
         count++;
      }
      else if (change > 9)
      {
         change = change - 10;
         count++;
      }
      else if (change > 4)
      {
         change = change - 5;
         count++;
      }

      // This is already checked in conditional
      // Use just else.
      // else if (change > 0)
      else
      {
         change = change - 1;
         count++;
      }

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Without the `while` loop the function increments `count` at most by 1.

Comment: But I still don't get the outcome i want.

Comment: I wanted to run the function "check".

Comment: @FaizMomin, I realized `count` is a global variable. Never mind my edits.

Comment: @R Sahu can you fix my code so it works. i am trying to find the change of an input using the least amount of coins. The only coins I can use are 25, 10, 5, 1.